# How to speed up dpkg (binary) package build

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, dpkg

I will be building debian package multiple times in a day, and each build takes
more than 8-9 minutes!
I was checking if there is any way to speed it up (`dpkg-deb --build`, binary pkg)
I tried to use `tmpfs` mounted partition to build, but that didnt help much. I think most of the time is spent in the compression! but the size
of the package will be too huge if I use `-Znone`. I tried to run it with `eatmydata` but that didnt seem to have any effect!

Any other methods that I can employ to speed up the build ?

Comment: It would be prudent to get metrics on exactly what your speed bottleneck is.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M, I checked without compression, and the package got created under 1 minute, whereas with compression its taking longer. Because even after compression the size will be close to 300MB.